# SSL waarning during phpmyadmin configuration

Tags: ssl, phpmyadmin

Sorry, I'm a beginner and I'm starting to configure my vps. 
Configuration :

```
débian 9 stretch
apache2.4.45
mariadb : 10.4
php 7.4.4
```

When I perform `apt install phpmyadmin`, I don't get any alert message regarding `SSL`. However when I try to update `phpmyadmin`, I get an alert message:

> SSL is not used

How to keep `SSL` protection?

P.S. - I have an HTTPS connection with my domain.com.

```
Server: localhost via unix socket
Server: mariadb
**Connection to the server: SSl is not used**
server version: 10.4.12 mariaDB-1: 10.4.12 + maria-stretch mariadb.org binary distribution
protocol version: 10
.....

phpmyadmin:
Version: 5.0.2
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: i don't see what it has to do with mysql?

Comment: Can you provide a copy of your error? How are you trying to update your PHPMyAdmin? Are you using wget or curl from command line? Is it showing you an error about a source not being secure? You could skip SSL check with --no-check-certificate with wget.